# Load balancing in GCE to cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I'm trying to set up Load balancing to my cluster that I created via container engine but I keep getting 502 Server Error.

Here is what I do.

1. I make sure that my service really runs taking this ip in kubernetes dashboard 
   [image]
2. I have only one instance group. So this belongs cluster
   [image]
3. 80 port is open for every instance in Firewall rules
4. I created a load balancer with this configuration. As you can see I set the only instance group I got, also I set up health check. The health check is http endoint /api/ping/ that returns HTTP 200 with body "pong". But I keep getting 502 ERROR. I understand it happens because health check doesn't pass. Apperently it's because when load balancer is sending request it's sending directly to instances, instead of to docker containers. If I go by ip of vm isntance where I host my cluster I will get nothing as well.
   [image]

I want to do it so I could switch traffic between different clusters If I decide to create a new one, also I would be able to balance https traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone so I will post the answer.

I created my pods via UI kubernetes using their consructor-form. When I used this form ports were not exposed to the host machine(Even I marked them as External ports). I wrote an yaml config and exposed ports there to host machine. After this balancer started working.
I used this block to expose 80 port to host machine

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 80
  hostPort: 80
  protocol: TCP
```